# Identification of non-linear functions:polynomial+exponential

Tags: least-squares, numerical-optimization, system-identification

Is there a way to perform a non linear least square to identify the following function:

$$\alpha_2\cdot x^2 + \alpha_1\cdot x + \alpha_0 + \beta e^{\frac{\gamma}{x}}=Y$$

I aim at identifying the parameters $\alpha_i, \beta $ and $\gamma$ without iteration.The exponential term is making it difficult to use [the Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), and I wonder if there is any other technique or to re-write the equation

Comment: You said it yourself. You need to do _non-linear_ least squares to solve this non-linear problem. You cannot simply do linear least squares because of the exponential term. Your wikipedia link has another link to NNLS that will no doubt prove useful.

Comment: I am wondering if a manipulation of the equation can help to get a closed-form solution.

Comment: NNLS does not necessarily yield an exact solution. Rather there are several NNLS algorithms that iteratively improve your approximation to the solution. You usually stop when you are within a given tolerance or when you have performed more than a given max number of iterations.

Comment: Shall I assume that $\beta e^{\gamma}$ constant?

Comment: Maybe you wrote something wrong in the question, but it seems to me the answer is clearly $\alpha_2 = \alpha_1 = \alpha_0\ = \beta=0$ Or is that supposed to be a $Y$ on the RHS

Comment: @OccupyGezi , in the case $\beta e^\gamma=0$, the linear least square will be easily applied. unfortunately, it is not the case

Comment: @Greg I just corrected the equation. Even if $Y=0$, we will still be interested in the non-zero parameters (i.e the parameters are physical ones)

Comment: @user2536125 I agree with your point; but is it fixed? $\beta e^{\gamma}=C$ ?

Comment: @OccupyGezi sorry again, somehow, the fraction was $\beta e^{\frac{\gamma}{x}}=Y $omitted. Hence this term is not constant any more.